# Work with maps and very many coordinates

Tags: gps, maps, coordinates, openstreetmap

I have to develop an application in which there is a map (Google or OpenStreet etc).

To create this I have about a million points of GPS coordinates, by which I have to draw a tracces (path).
I am using the **Gmap.Net**, but map is very slow when applied to a large number of points.

I beg your advice on which component is better to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to try doing caching on maps.

Also take a look on calculating on million points, probably there are other things which are effecting your load time.

DB, wrong logics etc

also try looking this.

http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/245963